# what algorithm can save one bit of storage space for each arbitrary 32bit number in a LUT

Tags: algorithm, compression, lossless

a lookup table has a total of 4G entries, each entry of it is a 32bit arbitrary number but they never repeats. 
is there any algorithm is able to utilize the index of each entry and its (index) value(32bit number)to make a fixed position bit of the value is always zero(so I can utilize the bit as a flag to log something). And I can retrieve the 32bit number by doing a reverse calculation. 
Or step back and say, whether or not I can make a fixed position bit of every two continuous entries always zero?

my question is that is there any universal codes can make each arbitrary 32bit numeric save 1 bit. so I can utilize this bit as a lock flag. alternatively, is there a  way can leverage the index and its value of a lookup table entry by some calculation to save 1 bit storage of the value.

Comment: my question is that is there any universal codes can make each arbitrary 32bit numeric save 1 bit. so I can utilize this bit as a lock flag.

Answer (score 2):

It is not at all clear what you are asking. However I can perhaps find one thing in there that can be addressed, if I am reading it correctly, which is that you have a permutation of all of the integers in *0..2<sup>32</sup>-1*. Such a permutation can be represented in fewer bits than direct representation, which takes *32*2<sup>32</sup>* bits. With a perfect representation of the permutations, each would be *ceiling(log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>32</sup>!))* bits, since there are *2<sup>32</sup>!* possible permutations. That length turns out to be about 95.5% of the bits in the direct representation. So each permutation could be represented in about *30.6*2<sup>32</sup>* bits, effectively taking off more than one bit per word.

Comment: that would be fun to implement! :)